# Neo4j How to Export one collection and Import as new collection

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am using the neo4j database. I want to export the collection including data and their relationships.
after export needs to import a new collection with a new name.

Eg:

1. Export the data from (Member) Collection
2. Import the Member collection as Students in my database

**Member -------> Students**

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by (Member) Collection - do you mean you want to export the whole database? Just a label? Rename Member to Student?

Comment: yeah - Chris Skardon

Comment: 'Yeah' to what? I asked 3 questions there. Could you elaborate more in your question with what you have done, and exactly what you want?